# How to display an Image after the main page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to display a thumbnail version of a logo in the header after I get past the main page and when the content starts. I'd also like it to disappear again once I go back to the main page. I've attempted some JavaScript but if anyone has any feedback or suggestions on how to fix it. I added some code to a JSFiddle for help.

HTML

```
<header>
    <img src="img.png" id="logo" />
</header>

<div id="mainPage">
    <img src="img.png" />
</div>

<div id="main">
    This is the content page.
</div>
```

CSS

```
header {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#mainPage {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 500px;
}
#mainPage img {
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#main{
    height: 500px;
}

#logo {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS

```
function showImg() {
    var img = document.getElementById('logo');
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    if(h < 600) {
        img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    else {
        img.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nkjqLyfg/2/

Comment: How is your function called?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to add that, I have it just being called in a script tag where I want it to check to see. So it's right after 'header'  and right after the 'mainPage'

Comment: @tjg92 Basically, what you did is execute the function twice when the page loads, and then you never call it again. That's not going to work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [my fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/hdrs0v7m/), you just need to set up your function as a handler for the `scroll` event. Also, different browsers have different ways of expressing the current scroll position. The following works in Chrome:

```
function showImg() {
    var img = document.getElementById('logo');
    var scrollY = window.scrollY;
    if(scrollY < 600) {
        img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    else {
        img.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}

document.addEventListener("scroll", showImg);
```

Comment: Be sure to check multiple browsers. I was too lazy to look up the others. At least verify Firefox, Safari, and IE11.